# Creating an Expectation Suite With an Automated Profiler Great Expectation

Tags: python-3.x, great-expectations

I am a newbie to great expectations and trying to set up but facing the below issue while creating an expectation Suite with an Automated Profiler.

```
C:\Users\user\great_expectations>great_expectations --v3-api suite new
Using v3 (Batch Request) API

How would you like to create your Expectation Suite?
    1. Manually, without interacting with a sample batch of data (default)
    2. Interactively, with a sample batch of data
    3. Automatically, using a profiler
: 3

A batch of data is required to edit the suite - let's help you to specify it.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\great_expectations.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\great_expectations\cli\cli.py", line 190, in main
    cli()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\great_expectations\cli\suite.py", line 151, in suite_new
    _suite_new_workflow(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\great_expectations\cli\suite.py", line 335, in _suite_new_workflow
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\great_expectations\cli\suite.py", line 268, in _suite_new_workflow
    suite: ExpectationSuite = toolkit.get_or_create_expectation_suite(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\great_expectations\cli\toolkit.py", line 82, in get_or_create_expectation_suite
    default_expectation_suite_name: str = get_default_expectation_suite_name(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\great_expectations\cli\toolkit.py", line 131, in get_default_expectation_suite_name
    suite_name = f"batch-{BatchRequest(**batch_request).id}"
TypeError: BatchRequest.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data_asset_name'

C:\Users\user\great_expectations>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and, for me, the problem came from a badly configured data source. What I suggest you to do is to test your data source config and see how many datasets it found:

```
from ruamel import yaml
import great_expectations as ge

context = ge.get_context()

datasource_config = {...}
context.test_yaml_config(yaml.dump(datasource_config))
```

When running this, the test_yaml_config will output a report on how many assets it found.

If it didn't find any, then you'll run into the issue you're describing when you'll try to create a suite on your data.